# Loading EDMX based on the condtiion

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have multiple Data Models created with the Entity framework (EDMX), and want to load based on specific conditions (similar to factory model) like so:

```
demoEntity obj
if(condtion1)
{ 
  obj= new firstmodel();
}
else if
{
  obj= new secondmodel();
}
```

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: what's firstmodel() and secondmodel()? How do you want to work against the model that is loaded dynamically? you need to provide more details.